# How to implement JPA in Play Framework in a standard way

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have gone though https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA

But it doesn't feel like a stardard way. I would like fill my jdbc connection in `persistence.xml` instead of application.conf

like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="TestPersistence"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.example.pojo.Employee</class>
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
 <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpadb" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
    value="mukesh" />
    <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
    value="database" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

instead of filling the jdbc connection in application.conf like

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpadb"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="mukesh"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=TestPersistence
```

Also if there is no other way to get jdbc connection in persistence.xml how can we define more than one jdbc connection in application.conf. like if i have a mysql for users and oracle db for posts.

NOTE: the source code posted are just dummy copied from public domain to show the briefly problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Play's DB module.  You can have your own module defined, and load your database connection and run it in isolation.

I would check out https://github.com/playframework/play-isolated-slick as an example -- here the UserDAO is bound through to SlickDAO in the Play module:

https://github.com/playframework/play-isolated-slick/blob/master/modules/play/app/Module.scala#L19

and the database provider is provided:

https://github.com/playframework/play-isolated-slick/blob/master/modules/play/app/Module.scala#L27

but you don't have to use `Database.forConfig("myapp.database")` -- you can define any config you feel like.